# Vue3 setup script in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, pinia

Im trying to build a Vue app with Vite, the problem is I define a Pinia store in the setup script and extract the actions like it's mentioned in the [Pinia docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#using-the-store) to use the action in a method in the normal script tag. This works when i use the Vite dev server but as soon as i build it every const from setup script is undefined in normal script.

I break it down to this, the problem can be reproduced if you try this on https://sfc.vuejs.org/:

```
<script setup>
const hi= 'hi';
</script>

<template>
  <h2>{{msg}}</h2>
  <button @click="sayHi">Say Hi</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name : 'test',
  data () {
    return{
      msg: '', 
    }
    },
  methods:{
    sayHi(){
      this.msg = this.hi;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

but if I replace the setup script with the setup method like below it works fine

```
setup(){
    const hi = 'hi'
    return{ hi }
  }
```

Is this the normal behavior? Or I'm  doing something wrong?

Comment: It's not recommended to use composition API with the options one, and using an extra `script` is recommended for some cases mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script)

Comment: script setup is syntax sugar that work in undocumented ways.  I'd suggest to avoid it for anything but normal cases that are described in the reference

Comment: Maybe coming from the fact that you have a template between 2 script tags? Try to group them maybe. Also, using just a const is maybe not that useful here. Does it work with a ref or you still have the issue?